# Two Errors - Mark an item as shipped with button on custom admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I made an admin panel with it's own database.

On the preorder.php page **which connects to another (its own) database** , after a user fills the form and stripe processes the order, I check if the charge was paid like this;

```
if ($charge->paid == true) {
    $amountReadable = $amount / 100; // to add in decimal points
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Your card was successfully billed for $'.$amountReadable.'</div>';
    $status = "paid";
```

then I connect to both the main database and the admin database (they both have the 'orders' table) and insert this query:

```
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
 if (!$connect){
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect);

 $query = "INSERT INTO 'DB_NAME'.`orders` (`email`, `name`, `qty`, `product`, `amount`, `stripe_customer_id`, `stripe_charge_id`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `timestamp`, `status`) VALUES ('$email','$cardName', '$qty', '$product', '$amountReadable', '$customer->id', '$charge->id', '$cardAddress1', '$cardAddress2', '$cardCity', '$cardState', '$cardZipcode', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, $status);";

 mysql_query($query);

 if (mysql_errno()) {
 $error = "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$query\n<br>";
 exit;   
 }
 mysql_close($connect);

 //insert into db for admin
 $connect = mysql_connect("--------","------","-------");
 if (!$connect){
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db(database2, $connect);

 $query = "INSERT INTO 'database2'.`orders` (`email`, `name`, `qty`, `product`, `amount`, `stripe_customer_id`, `stripe_charge_id`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `timestamp`, `status`) VALUES ('$email','$cardName', '$qty', '$product', '$amountReadable', '$customer->id', '$charge->id', '$cardAddress1', '$cardAddress2', '$cardCity', '$cardState', '$cardZipcode', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $status);";
```

Then on the admin panel **which has it's own database (database2 above)**, (orders.php) I pull these data into a bootstrap table like this:

**Edit 1#: I changed my orders.php in admin panel to something like:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1' data-toggle='table'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>qty</th>
<th>product</th>
<th>amount</th>
<th>address1</th>
<th>address2</th>
<th>city</th>
<th>state</th>
<th>zip</th>
<th>status</th>
</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><form action='markshipped.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='status' value='".$row["id"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Mark Item Shipped' /><form></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

then my markshipped.php is :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("----","----","----","----");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET status='shipped' WHERE id=$id");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm still not so comfortable with php/mysql and unfortunately I can't test it until someone buys anything as in stripe test mode none of the cards were not able to pass the form...

**So my problem is mainly:**

**I'm getting two errors saying:**

1.Undefined variable: id in /admin/orders/markshipped.php on line 9

-which is this line: `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET status='shipped' WHERE id=$id");`

2.Undefined index: status in /admin/orders/orders.php on line 88

-which is: `echo "<td>" . $row['status']. "</td>";`

So obviously I'm setting the `$status = "paid";` wrong and/or in wrong place.

**How do I correctly set these to be able to mark the item as "paid" initially then change it to "shipped" upon clicking the "mark item shipped" button on each row? Can you spot any other errors in my code?**

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch your $_POST['status'] with:

```
$id = $_POST['status'];
```

in markshipped.php in order to run your query. I would change the name of your hidden input field to 'id' and fetch $_POST['id'], as you want to submit the id.

You have a ` in this line (first insert query):

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`<<<<here , $status
```

and need to delete this / better set the column to on_update_current_timestamp in mysql

`$status` needs to be in ' ', I suppose `$id` is an integer, so you can leave it without ' '.

You are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_, I strongly recommend to rewrite the entire code in mysqli_, in special for your insert statements you really should use prepared statements and mysqli_. mysql_ is depreciated and unsafe. You are open to sql injections

why do you set id = NULL ? This should be an auto increment field, you shouldn't set it to null in your query.

If you put object data to your db, I'd use `'{$customer->id}'` or set

```
$customer_id = $customer->id;
```

before your query, makes it easier to check your query

You don't need to specify

`INSERT INTO **'database2'**.`orders

database2, the db is already selected - again: Use mysqli_ and prepared statements instead!

Example:

```
$customer_id = $customer->id;
$charge_id = $charge->id;
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`email`, `name`, `qty`, `product`, `amount`, `stripe_customer_id`, `stripe_charge_id`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssissssssssss', $email,$cardName, $qty, $product, $amountReadable, $customer_id, $charge_id, $cardAddress1, $cardAddress2, $cardCity, $cardState, $cardZipcode, $status);

$stmt->execute();
```

You need to setup the connection for mysqli_ instead for mysql_ if you do so

BLOCK 1:

```
<?php


if ($charge->paid == true) {
    $amountReadable = $amount / 100; // to add in decimal points
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Your card was successfully billed for $' . $amountReadable . '</div>';
    $status = "paid";
}
```

BLOCK 2:

```
<?php
$connect = new mysqli("localhost",DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$customer_id = $customer->id;
$charge_id = $charge->id;
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (`email`, `name`, `qty`, `product`, `amount`, `stripe_customer_id`, `stripe_charge_id`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssissssssssss', $email,$cardName, $qty, $product, $amountReadable, $customer->id, $charge->id, $cardAddress1, $cardAddress2, $cardCity, $cardState, $cardZipcode, $status);
$stmt->execute();




$connect->close();

//insert into db for admin
$connect = new mysqli("--------","------","-------","--------");

$customer_id = $customer->id;
$charge_id = $charge->id;
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`email`, `name`, `qty`, `product`, `amount`, `stripe_customer_id`, `stripe_charge_id`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssissssssssss', $email,$cardName, $qty, $product, $amountReadable, $customer_id, $charge_id, $cardAddress1, $cardAddress2, $cardCity, $cardState, $cardZipcode, $status);
$stmt->execute();
```

BLOCK 3:

```
$con = new mysqli("--------","------","-------","--------");
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders";
if ($result = $con->query($query))
{

echo "<table border='1' data-toggle='table'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>qty</th>
<th>product</th>
<th>amount</th>
<th>address1</th>
<th>address2</th>
<th>city</th>
<th>state</th>
<th>zip</th>
<th>status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['zip'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><form action='markshipped.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Mark Item Shipped' /></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}}
echo "</table>";
```

BLOCK 4:

```
$con= new mysqli("----","----","----","----");
// Check connection
$id = $_POST['id'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE orders SET status = 'shipped' WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
$con->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem:

> mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET status='shipped' WHERE id=$id");

`WHERE id=$id` should be: `WHERE id='$id'` (add single quotes on both sides of $id).

For your second problem:

> ...'$cardZipcode', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, $status);";

Same thing: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $status);` should be: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$status');` (you need to correct this one in two places).

I make these errors all the time too.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hey thanks I fixed those two but still getting the same two errors. I think it's because of the places I put them. preorder.php is in a database, admin panel (so the orders.php and markshipped.php) is in another database on the same server. Couldn't manage where and how to pass the $status = "paid"; to the dbs